# I have an issue with ng serve not correctly building application

Tags: angular

When I run ng serve --o, it boots up localhost:4200 but the cli a whole list of errors. I know the routing is correct and that it should be able to get the main page so suspect the errors lie with what the cli produces.

I have removed the node_modules folder using rm -rf node_modules and reinstalled using npm install, I updated my angular/cli and angular/core as well and have updated npm too. Currently using Angular CLI: 9.1.4, Node: 14.0.0 and Angular: 9.1.6

**ERROR:**

```
ng serve -o

chunk {firebase-auth} firebase-auth.js, firebase-auth.js.map (firebase-auth) 733 bytes  [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 59.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 9 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 12.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 5.71 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-05-12T16:21:03.474Z - Hash: ef13a8e1d195d57fddfe - Time: 12626ms

WARNING in ./node_modules/keyv/src/index.js 18:14-40
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in ./node_modules/cacheable-lookup/source/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/cacheable-lookup/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/got/dist/source/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/utils/get-body-size.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/utils'
ERROR in ./node_modules/cacheable-lookup/source/hosts-resolver.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/cacheable-lookup/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/got/dist/source/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http2-wrapper/source/auto.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/http2-wrapper/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http2-wrapper/source/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/http2-wrapper/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http2-wrapper/source/agent.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/http2-wrapper/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http2-wrapper/source/client-request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/http2-wrapper/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/got/dist/source/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http2-wrapper/source/auto.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/http2-wrapper/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/utils/timed-out.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/utils'
ERROR in ./node_modules/cacheable-lookup/source/hosts-resolver.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/cacheable-lookup/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http2-wrapper/source/utils/calculate-server-name.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/http2-wrapper/source/utils'
ERROR in ./node_modules/cacheable-lookup/source/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/cacheable-lookup/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/get-stream/buffer-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/get-stream'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/@ctrl/transmission/node_modules/got/dist/source/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/cacheable-request/node_modules/get-stream/buffer-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/cacheable-request/node_modules/get-stream'
ERROR in ./node_modules/clone-response/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/clone-response/src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/decompress-response/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/decompress-response'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http2-wrapper/source/client-request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/http2-wrapper/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http2-wrapper/source/incoming-message.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/http2-wrapper/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/responselike/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/responselike/src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/defer-to-connect/dist/source/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/defer-to-connect/dist/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http2-wrapper/source/agent.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/http2-wrapper/source'
ERROR in ./node_modules/resolve-alpn/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/resolve-alpn'
ERROR in ./node_modules/decompress-response/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/home/scott/angular/Prtl/Prtl/node_modules/decompress-response'
```

**Package.Json:**

```
{
  "name": "prtl",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.6",
    "@ctrl/transmission": "^2.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "firebase": "^7.14.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.11.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "services": "0.0.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.900",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a node package in the frontend, I'm guessing `@ctrl/transmission`?

Comment: You were bang on the money my friend, exactly as you said, trying to import it into the front end, found and fixed the error. Much appreciated! :) S